# How to tell if the iPhone is "face down" or "face up"?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin

I need to detect which direction the iPhone is facing so I can record from the non obstructed camera (Front or Back) when dropped.

This will be used in emergency situation and the phone is dropped, or placed in such a way that the active camera is recording nothing of value.

What API or technique can I use to determine this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the ProximityState property of the [UIDevice](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UIDevice/) class.  This will tell you if the screen is near an object (the user's face, or flat on the ground).

For newer devices, you can also use [CoreMotion](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/input/accelerometer/use_coremotion_with_accelerometer/).  A positive value on the Z-axis should correspond to the phone's screen being facedown.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple function I wrote to start tracking orientation changes so that you can know when it is face down or face up (or whatever orientation you're looking for):

```
func trackOrientationChanges() {
    UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, using:  
    { notificiation in
        if UIDevice.current.orientation == .faceDown {
            print("Device is face down")
        } else {
            print("Device is not face down")
        }
    })
}
```

Written in Swift 4 but the API is available since iOS 2.0+

Comment: This works only if users unlock screen portrait orientation. And for Swift4, use UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification instead of NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange for notification name.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Core Motion accelerometer. It reports the direction of gravity, which tells you which way the device is facing.